# Why my code is getting "10 $digest error"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wanted to make a simple app that check Browser's size and mark it.
However, I noticed an error message 
"Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!"

```
app.controller('AppCtrl',function($window,$scope){
$scope.windowHeight;
$scope.windowWidth;

$scope.getWindowSize = function(){
    return {
        h:$window.innerHeight,
        w:$window.innerWidth
    };
};

$scope.$watch($scope.getWindowSize,function (newValue,oldValue){
    $scope.windowHeight = newValue.h;
    $scope.windowWidth = newValue.w;
});


});
```

HTML Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html ng-app="size-util">
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <script src="angular.js"></script> <script src="colorBorder.js"></script> 
   </head>
   <body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
      <div color-border='blue'>Welcome!</div>
      {{windowHeight}} {{windowWidth}} 
   </body>
</html>
```

The above is my code.
What's wrong with my code?
Was I wrong with $watch stuff?
Please Let me know the problem . T_T

Comment: Can you show what is bound to the HTML template?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="size-util">
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="angular.js"></script>
 <script src="colorBorder.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<div color-border='blue'>Welcome!</div>
{{windowHeight}}
{{windowWidth}}
</body>
</html>

Comment: `$scope.$watch($scope.getWindowSize, function` should be `$scope.$watch('getWindowSize()', function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely watch a function for the return value. `$watch` compares old and new values for difference (dirty-checking), but your function always returns a new object that it generates, and so the object comparison is always `oldObj !== newObj`, and so it triggers another digest cycle waiting for the values to stabilizie, which they never do.

So, one way to avoid this is to only return a new object when any of its values change:

```
var windowSize = {};
function getSize(){
  var h = $window.innerHeight,
      w = $window.innerWidth;

  if (windowSize.h !== h || windowSize.w !== w){
    windowSize = {h: h, w: w};
  }

  return windowSize;
}

$scope.$watch(getSize, function(newVal){...})
```

Note, however, that this, on its own, does NOT trigger a digest, and so, you will not see any changes just by resizing the window, until something else is triggering a digest.

Comment: Is there any problem to trigger a digest?

Comment: You *can* trigger a digest (with `$scope.$apply`), but be very careful with this. window `resize` event is raised very rapidly, and causing the entire digest cycle can be make your application extremely slow. Some things to consider is to introduce some delay in triggering a digest. Another, if you are implementing it in a directive that just renders the window size in its small DOM subtree is to use `$scope.$digest` - which propagates digest only to the subtree.

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.getWindowSize = function(){
    return {
        h:$window.innerHeight,
        w:$window.innerWidth
    };
};
```

The above function returns a new object every time.

```
$scope.$watch($scope.getWindowSize,function (newValue,oldValue){
    $scope.windowHeight = newValue.h;
    $scope.windowWidth = newValue.w;
});
```

here newValue and oldValue are two different objects.

Pass the third argument as `true`(deep watch) to the $watch function.

```
$scope.$watch(watchFn, listernFn, deepWatch)
```

Comment: You are right that the values are always different, but why and how does deep watch help?

Comment: Deep watch will compare all the properties of the object otherwise only the references are compared.

Comment: Ah, that's true. Although I would stay away from deep-watch and just return a different object when it has changed, or same object otherwise

Answer (score -1):

I doubt you gonna make it work (*and even if you do it's going to be very inefficient*). `The $scope.watch() function creates a watch of some variable`. In your case, it's a function you're tracking and it doesn't change over time (the function itself stays the same). I suggest you to go with `directive` if you want to track `window.resize`: http://microblog.anthonyestebe.com/2013-11-30/window-resize-event-with-angular/

Comment: Why is it any more significantly inefficient than watching any other property? And, `$watch` allows for a function to be watched for its the return value - not a comparison of a function object to itself, so the statement "it doesn't change over time", implying that a $watch would not fired, is incorrect.

Comment: It's inefficient because directly watching for `resize` is wrong. It should be wrapped in some sort of debounce function or better implement a `directive`.